# Adding and retrieving markers on GoogleMaps with AsyncTask for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

I'm sorry for the long title but I wanted to be specific.

The objective is to add a marker on to a Google Map fragment and have it so that the marker can be seen by other NEARBY users that are using the app.

I did a lot of searching and it seems AsyncTask is the best tool/service to use to make this happen. However, as I continue to complete this objective, I still get people telling me to use 'custom services' and not use AsyncTask which still makes me doubt this path I'm taking.

So what I've done so far is:

```
class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        globalMap.addMarker(posty.getMarker()
                .anchor(0.5f, 1));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Double... params) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Posty is just an instance of a class that prepares a special custom marker. 
I call

```
 new TestAsyncTask().execute(latitude, longitude);
```

when the marker is ready to be posted. It works, it posts the marker successfully. However, I have no idea how to retrieve nearby markers posted by other users. I'm not sure exactly how the parameters are useful (in .execute), I just tried something that I saw from a vague tutorial.

If anyone can lead me in the right direction with this or perhaps offer an alternative solution (since I'm not very far on this), it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561038/android-google-maps-async-task-add-markers

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need web service to get Others markers to your map.It like this way.You need web service with these functionality.
  To get others markers.

getMarkersInRange(your current location,range of merkers)

To Post your Marker

postMarker(your location)

You need two async task for post your current location and get others location to your map. And web service responsibility to save the markers and return response when users send getOthersMarker request.I hope you understand the how the web service works.